# difference between bridge mode or just turn DHCP off for ISP modem

Tags: networking, router, modem

What is the difference between putting a modem (from Spectrum/Brighthouse ISP, etc) in bridge mode vs just turning DHCP off?

If you just turn DHCP off on a modem and let another device handle DHCP but you give that device the same static IP (by mistake) would it cause the modem to handle outside traffic (remote SFTP or OpenVPN for example) differently?

Comment: Router mode would also dial PPPOE, but not in bridge mode.

Comment: Would you suggest Bridge Mode over turned-off-DHCP Mode for extending my home network with a spare router?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a modem/router is in bridge mode, it completely disables the entire routing part and all traffic is instantly forwarded to the first port of the device. The other ports become disabled. So bridge mode is far more than just disabling DHCP. You basically turn a modem/router into a modem only. You can't do port forwarding either because every port is automatically being forwarded.

As for duplicate IP's, devices in your network would no longer be able to communicate with the modem, and as such, you'd loose internet access.